# Symfony 3.2 Random "Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class" for entities in CamelCase

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine

I am facing a strange problem on Symfony 3.2

The doctrine entities reversed engineered by Symfony (doctrine:mapping:import) for tables named in CamelCase like MimeType, TicketCategory, DocumentKind are named as Mimetype, Ticketcategory, Documentkind. (no camel case, just the first letter capital).

Because of my obsession of readability, I always have manually changed these entity names back to CamelCase. I never had problems with this practice since Symfony 2.8. In my two recent fresh 3.2 projects, entities with CamelCase names are problematic. They are accepted at first but later, they intermittently cause a "Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class". This error is triggered when clearing cache, when running schema:validate, and as an exception in the HTML output of the application.

I have tried clearing cache with nodebug, and with no-warmup with no success. The only progress I made is when temporarily rename MimeType.php to MimeTypex.php, clear cache, then rename back to MimeType.php. The entity name is temporarily accepted, but the problem returns after a short while.

Interestingly, Symfony is not complaining about the two dozen other entities with no camel case in the name.

Anyone else experiencing this? Could this be a bug when Symfony generates the cache files based on the project files? I manually deleted the cache in var/ with the problem persisting. Is there any other doctrine/symfony cache anywhere else to clear?